# How cond works in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

```
(define (list-ref items n)
  (cond ((null? items) "Out of range exception")
        ((= n 0) (car items))
        (list-ref (cdr items) (- n 1))))

(list-ref (list 1 2 3) 6)
5
```

Why it always return value of `(- n 1)`? Why it doesn't execute `(list-ref (cdr items) (- n 1))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot an `else` in the final clause.

Instead, it used `list-ref` as the condition (which is always truthy, since all procedures are truthy), and evaluated your other two subforms and returned the last one.

Comment: I understand. But why compiler didn't evaluate `(list-ref (cdr items) (- n 1))`?

Comment: It did. It evaluated `list-ref` as the truthiness condition (which is always true), and the `(cdr items)` and `(- n 1)` as the "then" expressions. The value of the last is returned.

Comment: In Scheme, only `#f` is considered false. Every other value is considered true.

Comment: Ok, if value of `list-ref` is true, why it didn't return value of `(cdr items)`?

As I understand it transforms to `(if(list-ref) then
                                                       (cdr items)
                                                       otherwise (- n 1))`

Comment: No, `cond` clauses have an implicit `begin`, so more like `(if list-ref (begin (cdr items) (- n 1)))`.

Comment: Thanks you very much!